# Writing more than 20,000 cells to a table in Excel with Office.js fails

Tags: javascript, excel, office365, office365-apps, office-js

I am writing data to an Excel table using the setDataAsync function on the binding for the table. Everything works until I go over 20,000 cells. After this point I get the following OSF.DDA.Error in callback result:

**code: 2014, message: "Note: The number of cells in a table is suggested to be below 20,000 cells", name: "Data Write Reminder"**

Is there an option anywhere to ignore this warning? This is quite a severe limitation when using a table to import data into a workbook.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have read the docs. This is a limitation but you can get round it by setting the start row option for [setDataAsync](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/binding.setdataasync) and breaking the writes to the table up into <20000 cell chunks.

Comment: If you are targeting Excel 2016 / Office Online / iOS, you can also use our new 2016 wave of Excel APIs:  https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/tree/master/excel